# Spring dao exception translation behaving differently in test and production

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm, jpa, exception

I'm using Spring exception translation in my application to translate exceptions from the underlying ORM framework (Hibernate) and I have discovered that ConstraintViolationExceptions are being translated differently in my test and production environments.

In my groovy unit test, I have the following...

```
    // provide a non-unique name for a department entity
    shouldFail(DataIntegrityViolationException, {

        Department d = new Department(name: 'HR')
        departmentDao.persist(d)
    })
```

This works fine - the expected DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown due to an underlying **org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException**. In my groovy service code, I have the following block of code which should catch the same DataIntegrityViolationException...

```
    try{
        departmentDao.persist(department)
    }
    // There may be a constraint violation if a department with the same name already exists
    catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){...}
```

However at runtime, Spring is not translating the exception and so the runtime Hibernate exception propagates its way up the stack.

There is mention of an org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException in the stacktrace which, according to the docs is a "JPA-specific subclass of UncategorizedDataAccessException, for JPA system errors that do not match any concrete org.springframework.dao exceptions." ...

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]

The only discernable difference I can see is that my test is backed by HSQLDB while the production code is backed by an MsSql database. Can anyone explain why the exception translation is different in my test and runtime environments?

Cheers.

EDIT:

OK, Some further detail...

Both my test app context and production app context define the PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor as follows

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

As far as datasource is concerned, the test context uses a HSQLDB datasource which is configured in the application context as follows

```
<!-- HSQL-DB memory database; for testing only -->
<bean id="hsqlDs"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/db/store;shutdown=true" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence-test.xml" />
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="hsqlDs" />
</bean>

<bean id="hsqlEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="store" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The prod context is considerably simpler as it uses a JNDI datasource defined in Glassfish and a persistence unit defined in persistence.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" />
```

although if I configure the prod context to use LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean I get the same result.

It appears as though EntityManagerFactoryUtils is being called to translate the exception, but the exception is being translated differently in the two environments. The test environment translates the exception to an **org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException** but the production environment translates it to an **org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException** - see the production stacktrace below:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.myapp.Department]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:369)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy233.persist(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the test-appcontext and prod-appcontext? at least the relevant parts, meaning datasource and transactionmanager configuration. Is it possible that you have a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor bean defined in one of them, and not in the other?

Comment: may you import  a different  DataIntegrityViolationException  class .Sometimes another package include class with same name .And this quite difficult to see.